# Select the rows by the letter

Tags: r

Trying to select rows from my data which include special letter inside the word. That's how my data looks like:

```
> data

 Name     Age   City    Weight
Leonard    22   Kansas    78
Mark       45   New York  65
Jessica    24   Dublin    54
Elena      32   Mexico    61
```

I want to keep only rows which include names with "r". It doesn't matter if "r" is a first letter or somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
set.seed(2)
data1 <- data[grepl("r", data$Name), , drop = FALSE]
```

Let me know if it's what you wanted.

Comment: You can use `grep` also in this case (`grepl` gives boolean values, while the other gives integer: index values). Also, check `?grep` because it has many options, like `ignore.case` which you may find useful if "r" and "R" are the same to you.

Comment: or `subset(data,grepl("r",Name))`